# Segmented time-dependent covariate

Tags: spss, survival, cox-model

I'm performing the cox regression analysis, where I have the model with 1 time-independent (treatment (yes/no)) and 1 time-dependent predictor (blood pressure level).

Outcome is death (yes/no). Time until death is measured in days and the count starts after the date of treatment prescription (time=0 days) in patients.

Time-independent predictor (treatment) have a value 1 (yes) or 0 (no) at time=0 days and remains the same until either death occur or time of observation is over (censored).

Time-dependent predictor, in turn, may appear in the model at time 90 (on 90th day after treatment date).

I compute the segmented time-dependent predictors in a way as it described in SPSS help (BP - blood pressure):

COMPUTE T_COV = (T_ < BP1_time) * BP1 + (T_ >= BP1_time & T_ < BP2_time) * BP2 + (T_ >= BP2_time & T_ < BP3_time) * BP3 + (T_ >= BP3_time & T_ < BP4_time) * BP4....

**The question is:** how does SPSS deal with the time within the period from 0 to 90 days for the time-dependent predictor? Does it just ignore this time period and start to measure hazard at the day when the BP variable enters to the model?